# Solve this icositetragram

Tags: pattern

If everything lines up, this puzzle will take a year to solve. But pick your way through, and don't despair, your reputation depends on it.

Find the missing letters below.

CEVOTCPEGULUNUYA??RABENA

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The missing letters are:

> **RP**

Since this 24 letter sequence can be:

> Split into 12 pairs of letters, each corresponding to the 3rd and 2nd letters of the months of the year, in reverse order.
>
>  This is best illustrated by spelling out each month backwards, starting with December:
>
>  REBME**CE**D, REBME**VO**N, REBO**TC**O, REBMET**PE**S, etc.
>
>  The missing letters correspond to LI**RP**A.